# Data Whitening Block Diagram

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, bluetooth, radio

I would like to understand this block diagram and how it relates to the formula:
g(D) = D^7 + D^4 + 1

Supposedly this helps to generate a whitening word used within bluetooth radio, the empty boxes are shift registers. I just dont understand how that formula relates to the diagram. I don't know what this type of diagram is called either.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: looks kind of exactly like a CRC

Comment: this is not for a crc however it is somewhat similiar, in the crc examples ive seen there are xor gates between every stage coupling in pre-defined data bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That drawing is a graphical representation of a LFSR (Linear Feedback Shift Register). The whole element is a shift register and is one form of a state machine.

This particular representation comes from communications theory and one application is for the generation of PN (Pseudo Noise) generators.  The 7,4,1 nomenclature tells you that the 7th, 4th and 1st FF's (flip flops) take the output and those feedback locations will uniquely determine the count sequence.  Do note that the nomenclature is not uniform so check the actual mapping examples.

Note that not all combinations of feedback loops form PN sequences.  And indeed this combination 7,4,1 does not in fact generate a PN sequence.

If you want to read more I'd recommend "shift register sequences" by Solomon W. Golomb

Comment: Thanks, so its just Nomenclature representing feedback locations.Great! Ill look into that book.

Answer (score 3):

The white squares are likely D type flip flops all connected to a common clock line. Basically this an additive data scrambler. Here's a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrambler) link.

[image]

Here's a circuit of a multiplicative data scrambler and I'm showing it so you can see what I mean by the D type flip flops: -

[image]

I think your scrambler is the type used in WLAN - see [this](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/ads2008/wlan/ads2008/WLAN_Scrambler.html) article

Comment: Thanks Andy, I didn't know it was called a data scrambler, and now i better understand the inner workings. however i still don't understand how the equation ties into this.